# Check Mute Event?

Tags: java, android, mute

I have a mute switch in my application.
Now I want to check if the switch is checked or unchecked.

How could I do this?

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: use isChecked method of checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `setOnChangeListener` to your switch

Eg : `switch.setOnChangeListener()` etc.

Then inside this, you can check by using isChecked.

eg.

```
if(isChecked) {
//do something ect...
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can check like below code;

```
   Boolean switchState = simpleSwitch.isChecked();

  if (switchState==true)
   {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"checked..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  else
   { 
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"not checked..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the previous answer stated, people normally use the `OnCheckedChangedListener`

but since Switch extends CompoundButton, it inherits the `isChecked()` method. Use it anytime to retrieve it's current status

This has been answered like a hundred times :)

Answer (score 1):

> hope you are using android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat;

```
switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
          // Do your stuff   
        }else{
          //  not checked
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code checks whether it is checked or not.

```
Checkbox muteSwitch = mute.getSelectedCheckbox();
if(null != muteSwitch ) {
  //not checked
} else {
  //Checked
}
```